# How should I handle multiple foreign keys that all point to the same column in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So let's say I have these two tables...

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='UnitsDef' AND xtype='U')
CREATE TABLE UnitsDef
(
    UnitsID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    UnitsName NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    UnitsDisplay NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
);

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='Dimensions' AND xtype='U')
CREATE TABLE Dimensions
(
    DimID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(0,1),
    DimX FLOAT,
    DimXUnitsID INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    DimY FLOAT,
    DimYUnitsID INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    DimZ FLOAT,
    DimZUnitsID INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY (DimXUnitsID) REFERENCES UnitsDef(UnitsID), 
    FOREIGN KEY (DimYUnitsID) REFERENCES UnitsDef(UnitsID),
    FOREIGN KEY (DimZUnitsID) REFERENCES UnitsDef(UnitsID)
);
```

I'll insert data into the first table similar to this...

```
INSERT INTO UnitsDef (UnitsID, UnitsName, UnitsDisplay) VALUES (0, 'inch', 'in.');
INSERT INTO UnitsDef (UnitsID, UnitsName, UnitsDisplay) VALUES (1, 'millimeter', 'mm');
INSERT INTO UnitsDef (UnitsID, UnitsName, UnitsDisplay) VALUES (2, 'degree', '°');
```

Am I going about this the right way?  This is a simplified version of the problem, but I need to know which unit each measurement is given in.  Is there a better design practice for this type of situation?

How would I handle the `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` for these foreign keys? If I try to cascade deletes and updates, SQL Server would not be so happy about that.

Comment: That is pretty much what you have to do. Not sure what you mean about sql server not being happy about cascade delete / update? I would think you aren't going to be doing any update. Meaning you aren't going to be changing inch from 0 to 8 or something. Keep in mind if you cascade delete it means it will delete your entire row in Dimensions if you delete a UnitsDef. Might be better to ON DELETE SET NULL.

Comment: @SeanLange is there a limit to how many fk you can have like this? A real table might have 10 or so. You're probably right about the `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` though. UnitDef likely won't ever change.

Comment: Might need to double check if that works with multiple foreign keys. Somewhere in my brain I am remember that using SET NULL or DELETE with multiple foreign keys to the same column may cause the multiple cycles error. Test it out and see. There really is no limit, well there is but those limits are absurdly high.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is pretty good.  I would make the suggestion right off that `UnitsId` be an identity column, so it gets incremented.  Your inserts would then be:

```
INSERT INTO UnitsDef (UnitsName, UnitsDisplay) VALUES ('inch', 'in.');
INSERT INTO UnitsDef (UnitsName, UnitsDisplay) VALUES ('millimeter', 'mm');
INSERT INTO UnitsDef (UnitsName, UnitsDisplay) VALUES ('degree', '°');
```

You should also make the string columns unique in `UnitsDef` and give them case-sensitive collations.  After all, `Ml` and `ml` are two different things ("M" is mega and "m" is milli).

You might also want to combine the units and values into a single type.  This has positives and negatives.  For me it adds overhead, but it can help if you want to support a fuller algebra of types.

Comment: I'm still on the fence about `UnitsID`.  I initially had it as `IDENTITY`, but recently removed that.  In the final version, I'll probably put it back in.